# have error in removeBoid & remove 1 of list

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

in `flock.removeBoids().` error incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1
and in **flock** maybe there are problem in remove 1 of list??

**main**

```
if (e.target.hitTestObject( flock)) {
    dokkaebiIsHurt = true; // Show the crazy filters on the dokkaebi.
    // Start the timer, to eventually make the runner look like normal again.
    myTimer.start();
    //removeChild(flock);

            flock.removeBoid();
            score += 1; 
    updateTextFields();
    trace(score);
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveArrow);
    removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));
    }
```

**flock**

```
public function grun():void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < ArrayList.length-1; i--)
        {
            //var b:Boid = Boid(ArrayList[i]);
            ArrayList[i].brun(ArrayList);
        }
    }

    public function removeBoid(b:Boid):void
    {
        //ArrayList.push(b);        
        ArrayList.splice(ArrayList.indexOf(b), 1);
        //removeChild(b);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward - the function `removeBoid` takes **one argument** - `b:Boid`. You call it like this: `flock.removeBoid();`. You do not pass any argument, so there is an error.

I'm amazed how you keep asking questions and not seeking for an answer yourself! Read some coding fundamentals instead of asking question every time there is an error in your code. At least read what the error says!

Comment: if i fill argument like this `flock.removeBoid(1);` appear error 1067 **implicit coercion of a value  of type in to un unrelated boid**, then how argument that true for it? 
thanks for the answer :)

Comment: You cannot pass `1` as an argument! You need to pass object of type `Boid`, it's written in the function.

Comment: if i fill argument `Boid` appear error **implicit of a value of type Class to an related type Boid**,

Comment: please help me, may i have your email address?